# Change the text of a button

Tags: jquery, button, text, fade

I'm doing a project that i have to change the text of a button with some fade effects. But i can't do it. I should click on the button and the text of it should fade out and them fade in with other text. I'm using jQuery for this

```
$("#button_fade").on("click", function(){
    if($(this).text() == "HELLO") {
         $(this).text().fadeOut(function(){
             $(this).text("WORLD").fadeIn();
         });
    }
});
```

I've already tried this code but it doesn't works.

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.text()` function returns a string, which doesn't have a `fadeOut()` method. You want to run that method on the element itself, you don't need to call `.text()` first.

```js
$("#button_fade").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "HELLO") {
    $(this).fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).text("WORLD").fadeIn();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button_fade">HELLO</button>
```

If your intent was to just fade out the text, not the whole button, you need to put an element inside the button and perform the fade effect on that.

```js
$("#button_fade").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).text() == "HELLO") {
    $(this).children("span").fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).text("WORLD").fadeIn();
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button_fade"><span>HELLO</span></button>
```

Comment: No, because `.text("WORLD")` returns the element. Methods that modify elements return the jQuery object so they can be used in a fluent interface.